# How to debug Microsoft Teams custom tab on Android

Tags: android, microsoft-teams

We have build a teams tab it works fine on Teams Desktop, but it fails on mobile without any error. The page is blank. If we open using Open in browser option the page works fine.

I tried using chrome F12, after enabling the developer mode, the chrome tab is not listed there. Is there a way to debug the Android teams custom tab using chrome F12 or some other way.

Answer (score 1):

[**Testing on mobile clients**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/design/tabs-mobile#testing-on-mobile-clients)

You need to validate that your tab functions properly on mobile devices of various sizes and qualities. For Android devices you can use the [DevTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools) to debug your tab while it is running. We recommend that you test on both high and low performing devices, as well as on a tablet.

See [Accessing DevTools from Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools#accessing-devtools-from-an-android-client)

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I wrote an article on how to setup a live debug session.
I focused there on SPFx tabs but the same principal applies to other apps You serve from localhost

https://mgwdevcom.wordpress.com/2022/03/28/live-spfx-debug-session-in-ms-teams-mobile-client/